# rmvnorm warning message: sigma is numerically not positive semidefinite

Tags: covariance-matrix

I am trying to set up a parametric bootstrap using the mean and covariance matrix from my model fitted with `nlm()` which converged with code 1. However, when creating new parameters using

`rmvnorm(1,mean=mod$estimate,sigma=solve(mod$hessian))`

I get the following warning message:

`Warning message:`
`In rmvnorm(1, mod$estimate, solve(mod$hessian)) :`
 `sigma is numerically not positive semidefinite`

The bootstrap completes without error and the results seem reasonable. My question is how reliable the results are?